# How to use filter in Java 8 to ignore values from an int array and to collection

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of errorCodes which I want to check whether or not they contain error codes in a separate array. If the error codes exist in list errorCode then I want to filter those out.

This is what I have so far

```
int[] ignoredErrorCodes = {400, 500};

  List<Error> errorCodes = errorsList.stream()
            .filter(error -> error.getErrorCode() != ignoredErrorCodes[0])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

how can I check against all values in the array ignoredErrorCodes instead of just one, using streams?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be better to store the ignoreds codes in a `Set` for faster lookup:

```
Set<Integer> ignored = Set.of(400,500);
List<Error> errorCodes = errorsList.stream()
            .filter(error -> !ignored.contains(error.getErrorCode()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `Set` might be overkill for a handfull of error codes (but doe snot hurt either), but in any way it makes more sense to create the collection once before the `filter`.

Comment: @tobias_k the `Set` *interface* doesn’t say anything about the actual overhead. In case of OpenJDK, the implementation returned by `Set.of(400,500)` will be a class containing two fields for the two values and its `contains` method looks like `boolean contains(Object o) { return o.equals(e0) || o.equals(e1); }`. What cheaper can it be? The great thing about this solution is, that it will adapt itself to the problem size, i.e. switch to a hash based implementation with a larger number of elements.

Comment: @Holger I did not mean to imply that `Set` would cause overhead and/or be slower than not using `Set`, just that the usual "Set is faster for lookup" might not really be relevant in this case. But as I said, it certainly does not hurt, either.

Comment: @tobias_k well, it’s also easier to handle than an `int[]` array which does not have a `contains` method…

Comment: @Holger Certainly, that's why I said that it makes sense to create a collection (any collection) before the filter. ;-)

Comment: I ran a test where there were error list contains the errors 400, 500 and 701. The filter then did not filter out the 400 and 500 error and the the final list list errorCodes contains all three errors instead of just 701. Why is this?

Comment: @user6248190 what's the type of `error.getErrorCode()`?

Comment: the type is an int @Eran

Comment: @user6248190 well, I don't have your Error class to try this code with, but testing it with a `List<Integer>` instead of `List<Error>` works, so the logic is correct. P.S. I also didn't use Set.of in my test (since I don't have Java 9). I used `HashSet` instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Eran is probably right, a Set is likely to best communicate your intent. If you really want to work with an array, though, consider:

```
import java.util.Arrays

errorsList.stream()
        .filter(error -> Arrays.binarySearch(ignoredErrorCodes, error.getCode()) < 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this please, or provide the complete code?

Comment: @user6248190 That code is complete (although it should read `< 0`, I edited it). It does rely on the array being sorted however.

Comment: Could have sworn I mentioned sorting the array. Thanks @daniu